# Difference between the P4 and P5 subtypes of P-type ATPases in plants

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, botany, proteins

In plants there are various kinds of P-type ATPases. What is difference between P4-ATPase and P5-ATPase?

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous differences between the various subtypes of P-type ATPases, simply because they have different amino acid sequences. Three important differences between P4 and P5 subtypes of P-type ATPases are the following:

1. **Structurally**, P4 ATPases have their supporting structural domain (S) in the C-terminus, while P5 ATPases have the S domain divided over the N and C termini. Figure 1 shows the basic structure of P-type ATPases.
2. **Structurally**, P4-ATPAses require a beta-subunit for proper function [(Poulsen *et al*., 2008)](http://www.plantcell.org/content/20/3/658.full). As the substrate for P5-ATPases is unknown, it could not yet be tested if they also require a beta-subunit.
3. **Functionally**, P4-ATPases are putative lipid flippases, while P5-ATPase pumps have so far (per the 2011 report cited) no assigned substrate specificity.

[image: P-type ATPase]
<sup>Schematic outline of P-type ATPases. Source: [Palmgren & Poul Nissen (2011)](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/pdf/10.1146/annurev.biophys.093008.131331)</sup>

<sub>**References**

**-** [Palmgren & Poul Nissen, *Annu Rev Biophys* (2011); **40**: 243–66](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/pdf/10.1146/annurev.biophys.093008.131331)

**-** [Poulsen *et al*., *Plant Cell* (2008); **20**: 658–76](http://www.plantcell.org/content/20/3/658.full)</sub>